# How to get the records from start with A to G in php and mysql

Tags: database

I have to show the records from A to G resutls from database. also tried the following code to show. Is there any mysql function available or should we use php to customize it.

Mysql query

```
SELECT *  FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'state' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'A%G'
```

Expected output

```
    States start from A thru G  States H thru J
Alabama                              Hawaii
Georgia                           Louisiana
```

Comment: `state` should be a taxonomy, it would make this question much easier and the queries would be _significantly_ faster. Terms are great for grouping/filtering/finding posts, post meta is good when you already know which post you need info on and want specifics

Comment: I have stored a state as  custom field using toolset type plugin